# Instance Variables not being passed into View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So maybe this is a bad question but I'm trying to create a pdf generator that dynamically puts a name from the database into the pdf via an html view.

Here is my download function for my controller.

```
class PdfGeneratorController < ApplicationController    
    def download    
        @actual_locale = I18n.locale
        I18n.locale = :en
        @user = User.find(params[:userid])
        @firstname = @user.first_name
        @lastname = @user.last_name
        
        html = PdfGeneratorController.new.render_to_string(
          {
            template: "/pdf_generator/download",
            layout: "user_courses/certificate_layout",
            
          }
        )
        pdf = Grover.new(html, wait_until: 'load').to_pdf
        send_data pdf, type: "application/pdf", disposition: 'attachment', filename: 'Certificate.pdf'
        I18n.locale = @actual_locale
    end
end
```

If I place a byebug just after where @user, @firstname, and @lastname are declared they all come back with the correct data. Within my view which is named **download.html.erb** I user @firstname and @lastname like so.

```
<h2 class="certificate--title"> Demo Certification</h2>
  <h4>is proudly presented to</h4>
  
  <h2 class="certificate--acquirer-name"><%= @firstname %> <%= @lastname%> </h2>
```

However when the pdf is generated there is no name in it. Finally I've tested with a byebug, and @firstname and @lastname come back as nil in the view. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: _"maybe this is a bad question"_ – there's no such thing :-)

Comment: @Stefan: except this site is full of them :) There may be no stupid questions (arguable), but there are a lot of bad ones: lazy, incomprehensible, badly written, etc. Fortunately for us, this question is not one of them.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you are creating a new controller instance, whereas you should just use the current instance.

```
html = PdfGeneratorController.new.render_to_string(
```

Should be:

```
html = render_to_string(
```

Creation of a  controller instance is typically done by the Rails framework and should not be done by yourself.

Comment: With this approach you probably don't have to explicitly set `template` either.

Comment: That fixed it! Thank you! I didn't realize that PdfGeneratorController.new initialized an entirely new controller, I thought I was simply calling the new function within the controller, good to know!

Comment: It doesn't really "reset" the instance variables. Instance variables are local to an instance of a class - its therefore wrong to expect that a completely separate instance would have the same instance variables. "I thought I was simply calling the new function within the controller" I think you may be confusing this with an instance method `#new`. The [class method `.new`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Class.html#method-i-new) creates new instances of a class.

Comment: @justUrAverageProgrammer If the intent is to call the `new` action in the controller use `new` (or `self.new`) instead of `PdfGeneratorController.new`. The former one is calling `new` upon a controller instance (aka a controller action), while the latter one creates a new controller instance. Normally you don't call one controller action from the other. If that is the case you might want to move the shared logic to a private controller method (if it involves rendering logic) or into the relevant model (if it does not involve rendering logic).